# how do a client knows that the server closed its socket

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

I am using the following client code. After a successful connect(), if server shuts down all its connections , how will my client knows about this server shutdown ? Is there any way to listen for this kind of events from client side code?

```
int sfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, tcp->p_proto);

struct sockaddr_in isa = getipa("localhost", 1025);

connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&isa, sizeof isa);

ssize_t size = recv(sfd, (void*)buff, sizeof buff, MSG_WAITALL);

puts(buff);

printf("Enter message to send\n");
scanf("%s",sendMsg);
send(sfd, (void*) sendMsg, 255, MSG_NOSIGNAL)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it exhibits zero research.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` returns zero if *this* connection has been closed by the peer, or -1 with an `errno` setting if the connection has encountered an error.

This is documented.

You don't care about the other connections.

You could also consider adding error checking to the rest of your code. Every one of those system calls can encounter an error.